# Caret not appearing in contenteditable div on right click in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

If we right click inside a contenteditable div, the caret appears at the position of right click or end, but it doesn't happen in Firefox. Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L9sFk/2/

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="padding-left:5px;height:30px;width:250px;border:2px solid;">
    sample text
</div>
```

Is this a bug, and what can be a possible workaround. The caret should appear at the right place. Using jquery focus on right click places it at the beginning always which is incorrect.

**Edit:**

I am using Windows 7 32bit - Firefox 29

Comment: Works fine here, FF29 on OSX.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am using windows ff29

Comment: I'm on 64bit win 7, FF29. works fine

Comment: @Reigel After right click a context menu wil open, but cursor doesn't appear in the background